# Gitlab mirroring failure notification on remote repository

Tags: gitlab

we have Gitlab repo's with mirroring to other repo's. but when mirroring fails for any reason we do not notified.

is it possible to have a notification up on failure on gitlab mirroring on remote repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the status from the gitlab api

```
curl -sS --header "Private-Token: <YOUR_TOKEN>" "https://<hostname>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>" | jq . | grep import_status
```

if your mirroring fails, the import_status will change to `failed`

about the alert, you can create a scheduled pipeline that runs every x minutes looking for this information.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpfull. I don't know why they give me -ve point on question.